# PowerShell bizarre variable process

Tags: powershell, arguments

I've been banging my head, about this ...

Created this simple PowerShell script :

test.ps1:

```
       Write-Host    $args[0]
       Write-Host  $($args[0])
       Write-Host "$($args[0])"
```

Now, run the script twice, with these parameters :

```
      powershell .\test.ps1 0E2C
      powershell .\test.ps1 0E2D
```

The first run returns :

```
      0E2C
      0E2C
      0E2C
```

The second run returns :

```
      0E2D
      0
      0
```

Why is that ? Why is powershell converting 0E2D to 0 ? Is it considering that 0E2D is an hexadecimal value and trying to convert it somehow ? But why, and why doesn't it do the same with value 0E2C ?

EDIT :Thank you all.

I solved the issue by using a variable, and forcing it to string
So, changing my TEST.PS1 :

```
Write-Host    $args[0]
Write-Host  $($args[0])
Write-Host "$($args[0])"
[string] $myvar = $args[0]
Write-Host "$myvar"
```

Now, when I run :

```
      powershell .\test.ps1 0E2D
```

I now get :

```
      0E2D
      0
      0
      0E2D
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, as for `0E2C`, PowerShell can't resolve it as a valid hex so, it will be passed as a string to `Write-Host`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- An *unquoted* argument such as `0E2D` is inherently *ambiguous* - it can be interpreted as either a string or a number. By default it *is* parsed as a number, but the original representation is *cached* - see next section.
- To avoid ambiguity:

  - Either: *quote* an argument you want to be interpreted *as a string*, e.g. `.\test.ps1 '0E2D'`

    - This puts the responsibility on the *caller* to know when there's ambiguity.
  - Or, preferably: explicitly [*declare typed parameters*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters) for your script instead of relying on the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args), such as `param([string] $StringValue)` or `param([decimal] $Value)`

    - This is preferable, because the caller is then free to pass the argument *unquoted* (unless it is a string and contains shell metacharacters), without having to worry about potential ambiguity.

---

- The existing, helpful answers explain that `0E2D` is interpreted as a [number literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Numeric_Literals), namely a decimal value in scientific (exponential) notation, typed as a [`[decimal]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Decimal), due to *suffix* `D` (`d` would work too, as type-specifier suffixes are generally case-*insensitive*).
- Let me complement them by explaining why `$args[0]` still showed the argument's *original string representation*, at least when used as-is.

In *argument* [parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), i.e when arguments are passed to command, *simple string values* (ones that contain neither spaces nor other shell metacharacters) *need not be quoted*.

This creates *ambiguity*, such as in the case at hand: is `0E2D` meant to be a *number*, or meant to be a *string* (`'0E2D'`)?

PowerShell's parameter (argument) parser handles this ambiguity as follows:

- if the unquoted argument *can* be parsed as a number, *it is*.
- if so, and if the *default stringification* of the number doesn't equal the argument as specified, the number is wrapped in a (mostly invisible) `[psobject]` instance that caches the *original (string) representation*, which can be recalled via `.psobject.ToString()`
- if the unquoted argument binds to an explicitly declared *typed parameter*, the originally parsed form is ultimately irrelevant, but it does matter in *unbound* argument-passing, i.e. when arguments are passed positionally in the absence of predeclared parameters, via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args).

Here's an explicit illustration using `1L` as a positional, unbound argument, which is parsed as `[long]` value `1`, with the original representation, `1L`, cached in the `[psobject]` wrapper:

```bash
PS> & { $args[0].ToString(), $args[0].psobject.ToString() } 1L
1   # default stringification of the [long] value that 1L was parsed as
1L  # original representation
```

The *default* display representation *implicitly* calls `.psobject.ToString()`:

```bash
PS> & { $args[0] } 1L
1L  # original representation - even though it was parsed as [long]
```

This - commendably - also applies when passing the argument to *external programs*, as PowerShell should make *no* assumptions as to whether the argument represents a number or not - that is up the target program:

```bash
PS> cmd /c echo 1L
1L  # original representation
```

---

Unfortunately, however - as your question shows - both *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core)* as of v7.2.6 - are *inconsistent* with respect to *when* they honor the cached string representation:

```bash
& { 
 $args[0]     # ditto for ($args[0])
 $($args[0])  # ditto for @($args[0])
 "$($args[0])"
} 1L
```

Arguably, *all* these commands should honor the original representation but only some of them do:

```bash
1L
1L
1
```

With `0E2D` as the argument, as in your question, the two PowerShell editions even exhibit differences: `$($args[0])` prints `0` in *Windows PowerShell* vs. `O2ED` in *PowerShell (Core)* 7.2.6.

---

Another inconsistency is that if you pass such an argument to `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), it is *only* the cached string representation that is ever honored, *not* the numeric type that the argument was actually parsed as:

```bash
PS> & { '{0:N1}' -f $args[0] } 1.234e0 # Argument is parsed as a [double]
1.234e0  # !! Formatting the [double] as a number with 1 decimal place failed.
```

However, this behavior was declared to be *by design* - see [GitHub issue #17199](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17199).

Answer (score 3):

Powershell interprets `0E2D` as a Decimal `0E2` which is `0*10^2` which is `0`
The `d` suffix is documented here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.2#real-literals

Answer (score 2):

It is interpreting `02ED` as a decimal number rather than a string due to the suffix `d` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.2)

So it's 0 x 10^2 (0E2) which is 0.

But the C at the end of 0E2C is not a suffix literal, so it's just a string.